# Regex: match words between certain characters, but not between other certain characters (in .NET)

Tags: .net, regex

I want to match all the words in brackets, including brackets, which are not between simple quotation marks (in .NET):

```
"[field1] = 'id1'" -> match "[field1]"
"[field1] = '[field2]'" -> match "[field1]"
"[ field1 ] = '[ field2 ]'" -> match "[ field1 ]"
"[ field1 ] = '[ field2 ] field3'" -> match "[ field1 ]"
"[field1] = ' [field2] ' And [field3] = '[field4] '' [field5]'" -> match "[field1]" and "[field3]"
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Voting -1 should not be allowed without a commentting the reason. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to match things "which are not between" other things, you may think to negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!' *)\[[^\]]*\](?! *')
```

The matched group is `$0`.
If I am not wrong, .NET regexps allow you to use non-fixed width expressions inside lookaround (but be aware that it is very expensive), so the regex above should do the job.

In other languages this is not allowed, but there is a workaround called "possessive quantifier" (`*+`):

```
(?<!') *+(\[[^\]]*\]) *+(?!')
```

The matched group is `$1`.
This works in all the languages in which negative lookaround and possessive quantifier are permitted ([example](https://regex101.com/r/chuq8O/2)).
About the meaning of `*+`, I suggest you [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42598007/4607733) on the topic.

But maybe the computationally simplest expression is:

```
[^'] *+(\[[^\]]*\]) *+[^']
```

The matched group is `$1`.

---

**Update**

This is a kind of heuristics:

```
(?<=^[^'\n\r]*(('[^'\n\r]*){2})*)\[[^\]]*\]
```

Or, maybe faster:

```
\[[^\]]*\](?=[^'\n\r]*(('[^'\n\r]*){2})*$)
```

The matched group is `$0`. Use it with [multiline mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) (`m` flag).

It will work if apexes inside the fields are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, horcrux. I need something similar to the first regex, but it matches also the [field2] in: "[ field1 ] = '[field2] aaa'". Btw, is the "<" char needed at the beginning of the regex? I think it's not.

Comment: `(?<!A)` is a structure meaning "not preceded by `A`", so the character `<` is needed.

Comment: @ChocapicSz Anyway, what if you have `'[field1] [field2] '`? Should they be matched?

Comment: No, they shouldn't.

Comment: @ChocapicSz Ok. And do you think there will be some false positives or false negatives if we use the heuristic "The field is not preceded by an odd number of apexes"?

Comment: For an example of what I meant, see the answer update.

Comment: @ChocapicSz So what about the last regex I've appended?

Answer (score 0):

As @horcrux also pointed out, you can use negative lookbehind and lookahead. Since apparently `C#` supports infinite repetition, you could get away with:

```
"(?<!(')\s*)" + "\[[^\[\]]+\]" + "(?!\s*$1)
```

Separated the three parts, the negative lookbehind, the capturing match and the negative lookahead.

Note also that since the lookarounds are non-capturing, you don't even need parenthesis around the middle part.

In `Java` this would be something like:

```
"(?<!(')\s{0,1000})" + "\[[^\[\]]+\]" + "(?!\s{0,1000}$1)
```

but it's kinda' hacky, as it would only work for `1000` spaces between the two.